# Comparing SQL Tables: Displaying The Full Set and Any Differences

Tags: sql

I wish to compare two sets of data and display the full union of the two sets, with added columns to show if a row appears in set 1, set 2, or both. I'm working in T-SQL

```
Table A  
|[ID] | [Movie] | [Year] |  
|-----|---------|--------|  
| 1   | Movie1  | Year1  |  
| 2   | Movie2  | Year2  |  
| 3   | Movie3  | Year3  |   

Table B  
|[ID] | [Movie] | [Year] |   
|-----|---------|--------|  
| 2   | Movie2  | Year2  |  
| 3   | Movie3  | Year3  |  
| 4   | Movie4  | Year4  |   


Desired Result:  
|[ID] | [Movie] | [Year] | [In Set A?] | [In Set B?] |  
|-----|---------|--------|-------------|-------------|  
| 1   | Movie1  | Year1  |    Yes      |     No      |  
| 2   | Movie2  | Year2  |    Yes      |     Yes     |  
| 3   | Movie3  | Year3  |    Yes      |     Yes     |  
| 4   | Movie4  | Year4  |    No       |     Yes     |
```

Is this possible to accomplish in SQL? I'd settle for having the added columns be just 1 column where the output was A, B, or Both.

Comment: There are also edge cases like same id having different data in the two tables, etc.

Comment: What database system you're using?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a FULL JOIN and COALESCE, this is assuming you can join on ID:

```
SELECT COALESCE(a.ID,b.ID)as ID
     , COALESCE(a.Movie,b.Movie) as Movie
     , COALESCE(a.Year,b.Year) as Year
     , CASE WHEN a.ID IS NULL THEN 'NO' ELSE 'YES' END as InSetA
     , CASE WHEN b.ID IS NULL THEN 'NO' ELSE 'YES' END as InSetB
FROM TableA a
FULL JOIN TableB b
 ON a.ID = b.ID
```

Demo:  [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/51a9a/2/0)

You could also Combine the last portion into one field:

```
SELECT COALESCE(a.ID,b.ID)as ID
     , COALESCE(a.Movie,b.Movie) as Movie
     , COALESCE(a.Year,b.Year) as Year
     , CASE WHEN a.ID IS NULL THEN 'In B Only'
            WHEN b.ID IS NULL THEN 'In A Only'
            ELSE 'In Both'
       END as InTable    
FROM TableA a
FULL JOIN TableB b
 ON a.ID = b.ID
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a `union all`:

```
select id, movie, year,
       (case when max(inA) = 1 then 'Yes' else 'No' end) as inA,
       (case when max(inB) = 1 then 'Yes' else 'No' end) as inB
from ( select id, movie, year, 1 as InA, 0 as InB
       from tableA
       union all
       select id, movie, year, 0, 1
       from tableB
     ) t
group by id, movie, year
```

This is slightly different from the `full outer join` solution.  That solution can multiply rows if there are duplicates in either table.  This solution will remove the duplicates, even within a table, so multiple rows would be shrunk to one row.

Comment: I like this approach, do my edits come up as suggestions or just get slapped into place?

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you. I love the internet...it's just people helping people!